# Evaluating the operation of Assembly code

Tags: architecture, mips, cpu-architecture

This is my homework assignment.

> Describe as concisely as possible what the following MIPS code
>   achieves? Assume that register $8 holds base address of array A.

```
addi $10, $0, 0
L1:
lw $16, 0($8)
slt $9, $0, $16
beq $9, $0, L2
addi $10, $10, 1
addi $8, $8, 4
j L1
L2:
```

Now what the answer I came up with is,

> The loop will continue to run infinitely if A[0] contains a value less
>   than or equal to 0.
>   Please guide me if I am wrong with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this just a bit more. What is happening on line 7 is important. What is `addi $8, $8, 4` doing? This will help you with your answer. I think your current answer isn't quite sufficient.

Comment: What I could make out of it is that it will keep on incrementing to the next index of the array A. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Right, that's a key part of it. Next, how does that relate to the `beq $9, $0, L2` instruction? See if you can revise your answer to the homework using that idea.

Comment: The index of the array A will keep on incrementing until and unless a value 0 is found in it. Am I right?

Comment: Closer. This is the next key instruction: `slt $9, $0, $16`. What's happening here?

Comment: Moreover (since the answer is already available to you) how does this change the loop behavior?

Comment: The program will iterate through the array until it finds a 0 or negative number in it.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a [MIPS instruction set reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html), let's translate the assembly code to an easier-to-understand form:

```
    Compute r0 + 0 and store to r10.
L1:
    Load word at address r8 + 0 to r16.
    If r0 is less than r16, then set r9 to 1, else set r9 to 0.
    If r9 equals r0 then goto L2.
    Compute r10 + 1 and store to r10.
    Compute r8 + 4 and store to r8.
    Goto L1.
L2:
```

Note that r0 always has the value zero.

Let's translate it further:

```
r10 = 0
while true:
    r16 = memory[r8]
    r9 = if r16 > 0 then 1 else 0
    if r9 == 0:
        break
    r10 += 1
    r8 += 4
```

Comment: The question that now disturbing me is, "What would r16 hold?"

Comment: Notice that r16 gets rewritten on every loop iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full, straight answer to the original question - "what does the code do?":

- We assume that r8 points to the start of an array of signed 32-bit integers.
- The code searches forward in the array for an element that is non-positive and stops if and only if it finds such an element. If it stops, then these properties hold:

  - r10 is equal to the array index of the found element. (Which is 0, 1, 2, or etc.)
  - r8 is equal to the address of the found element. (Which is the original value of r8 plus 4*r10.)
  - r16 is equal to the value of the found element (which is zero or negative).
  - r9 is equal to 0. (Condition code)

(The explanation is in my other answer post.)